# Reinstalling node-fibers for a Meteor app on Modulus.io?

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

I'm trying to port a Meteor application from Heroku to Modulus.io (hopefully will be able to test out sticky sessions and horizontal scaling).  I've demeteorized my app using the Modulus.io script, as spelled out in the following articles and repositories.

https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer
http://blog.modulus.io/demeteorizer

After demeteorizing, I zipped and uploaded, and got an empty deploy log and a white screen in the browser.  After a bit more research, I deleted the node_modules directory in the resulting demeteorized application, and then zipped and uploaded.  That definitely seemed to be the right move, because everything started deploying, and the logs got busy.

Here's the error I'm coming up with though:

```
Error: `/mnt/data/1/clinical-workqueues/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/1/clinical-workqueues/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/1/clinical-workqueues/server/server.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
Forever detected script exited with code: 1
Forever restarting script for 6 time
```

Does anybody know how I ought to go about 'reinstalling node-fibers' in the Modulus.io environment, using a demeteorized Meteor app?  I'm getting out of my league here, and am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions!

Comment: Could you manually install fibers by running `npm install fibers@1.0.0`, or adding it into your `package.json` and run `npm install`?

Comment: "fibers": "1.0.0" is already in the package.json file, and I don't have access to shell access to run npm install.  :(

Comment: It looks like the automatic parser that reads the package.json might not be installing the node modules specified inside it before the app is run. You might need to contact them and let them know. Usually Its supposed to be automatic and 'just work'

Comment: What version of Meteor are you running? Demeteorizer hasn't been updated to work with 0.6 yet. Some dependencies don't get added. That could be the issue.

Comment: Version 0.6.2, sadly.  That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Just released Demeteorizer 0.2.1 that adds support for Meteor 0.6.x apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a blog article that should help out others trying to deploy Meteor apps to Modulus.

http://blog.modulus.io/deploying-meteor-apps-on-modulus

Disclosure: I'm the author of Demeteorizer and co-founder of Modulus.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to upgrade to Demeteorizer 0.2.1, run a 'meteor add email' to my application, and then add the following dependencies to my package.json file:

```
"sockjs": "0.3.4",
"websocket": "1.0.7",
"mongodb": "1.2.13",
"mailcomposer": "0.1.15"
```